# Google Analytics for IOS v2 (Beta)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to get Visitors name in google analytics for iOS and how to stop tracking. How to Use Custom Dimension and Custom Metric.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See,

1)`Getting The Visitor's name in google analytics for iOS`-->
As far As I know it's Not possible that GoogleAnalytics track the Visitor Name.
The One Alternative can be,In such condition suppose your application has some login procedure to use your Application.In this case you can save that user's name and send that Name to the `Google ANalytics server` for tracking purpose.

2)`How to Use Custom Dimension and Custom Metric`--> I am not completely cleared `Custom Dimension and Custom Metric`.You should take a view of `Google ANalytics Documentation` regarding the Same .[Here is The Link For The Google Analytics Doc.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/devguide)

[see How Can you pass the Custom variable to the Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

I hope you this might helpful to you.

Comment: Google Analytics IOS V2(Beta) not having custom variable. how to send the username to google analytics server.

Comment: @Anamika as i said you can't send the userName to server. .https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources.Here is the Link for the SDK which contains Some sample code too.See some methods inside that code .And ALternative is use `trackedViewName` method for tracking the Category.here what you can do, you can pass the UserName to that method.